# How to use thread in PHP ?

Tags: php, multithreading, performance

I am working on PHP and working an SMS application. The problem occurs when I am going to send different sms  to different subscriber on by one. and I have more than 800000 subscribers. 
Currently, I am sending SMS via PHP loop, but it's taking time too much ( like 10 min and more. the database query is working properly (fast) but PHP script loop is slow ( because inside the loop I have written some script to call web service to send a message). And am unknown about thread too .

Comment: Could you give further information about the PHP you are using?, looks interesting, anyway this is the way you should follow: [Thread Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php)

Comment: You should completely change your approach. Not by using threads, but by introducing a job scheduler. You "main " script only registers single jobs which are then processed one by one (or in chunks of say 100) by "runners". That makes the overall architecture much more robust and also allows things like scaling over multiple systems.

Comment: A job scheduler with a queue and configurable batchrun that depends on system load and available resources.

Comment: if you not expecting any response from the webservice set the timeout for CURL post/get. This is the way you can speed up. I guess the time is mostly spend on waiting not on loop

Comment: Threads will increase the CPU and RAM usage so you'll end up with slow server.

Comment: This is what currently i am using php code. 

<?php  foreach ($msisdnList as $key => $msisdn) {

                sendSMS($msisdn, $UrlParameter);
            }


One more thing , i have to send all message with in 6 minute ( for all subscriber ie. around 850000 users) . 



?>